# Clarification in stochastic integration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In the book "Stochastic Processes" by Bass R.F. when he constructs the Stochastic Integral, at some point he defines for $Y$ predictable
$$||Y||_2= \left(\mathbb E \int_0^{\infty}Y_t^2\text{d} \langle M\rangle _t \right)$$
and he claims that if we have a predictable $H$ with
$$\mathbb E\left( \int_0^{\infty} H_s^2 \text{d} \langle M \rangle_s\right)<\infty$$ we can approximate it by a sequence $H^n_s$ of the form 10.3 in the book, namely:
$$X_s(\omega) = \sum_{j=1}^{J} K_{j}(\omega) 1_{(a_j,b_j]}(s)$$
with $K_j$ bounded (that is, sums of basic processes of the form $Y_s(\omega)=K(\omega)1_{(a,b]}(s)$). Now, his justification is that this can be done because he previously proved that the $\sigma$-field of predictable processes is generated by processes of this form (Lemma 10.1 in the book). If I understand correctly, what he means is that there exists a sequence $H^n$ converging to $H$ and this would imply that $||H-H^n||_2$ converges to $0$. But why is this true? Is he using some sort of dominated convergence? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi koizumi, I think that some points in  your notations need to be clarified, for example the dependence in "n" in the sum-expression your sequence $H_n$, and also the dependence in $\omega$ of the terms of the sums aswell. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge yes I tried to make the notation clearer... This sequence is a sequences of processes which take constant values on a finite number of intervals and nowhere else. He also suggests that for $H$ bounded, adapted and with continuous paths, taking $H^n_s=H_{k/2^n}$ if $k/2^n<s\leq (k+1)/2^n$ for $s<n$ and $H^n_s=0$ for $s\geq n$ will work, but I don't see why.